# Automate IIT Newsletter Creation

Tags: articles, extensions, user, update, emails

I am looking for assistance in creating a newsletter.
Tool that will create a newsletter
5-10 articles will generate in diff categories and sorts out based on category
Eventually we need a user interface so users can submit  articles in the system.
As well as update on its own in a timely manner.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to present the research that you've done. What existing offerings in the JED looked relevant, but didn't suit your needs?  Are you willing to develop your own solution or do you need something to be completely developed and packaged for your instant use?  Currently, this is not yet a great question for JSE -- it is just a list of demands.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Acymail extension to do the things you require as that is the one I am most famliar with, however there are other very mature extension capable of doing what you need in the JED, https://extensions.joomla.org/category/marketing/newsletter/